# Wide Ball rule when batsman switch hit

Tags: cricket

If an RHB switches and becomes an LHB and the ball was going to LHB's off-side, is it a wide just because anything on the leg side is a wide.[since the batsman is an RHB] when the ball comes to play ?

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE, before asking questions pls make sure it's not a dupe ie, not already discussed here on sports.SE :)